# Searching for best CMS to create Forum

Tags: crm

I am searching for a opensource/paid CRM by using which I can create Forum Web application.
Few features which I am expecting into it

1. Scalable
2. Can able to create group - Public as well as private
3. APIs availability to integrate with different applications
4. Analytics Reports
5. Push notifications can be sent through
6. Database Documentation
7. Integrate with Mobile app, or have modules to convert in mobile applications

Comment: Take a look at http://www.cmsmatrix.org/